# IONIC-: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

i am trying to build my ionic 6 app with this command on windows 10 `ionic cordova build android --release` but i get this error at the end:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\givlly\filos\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b C:\givlly\filos\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys still using cordova for android.
Use Capacitor, install, migrate it to capacitor compatible.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli